# How to read the Jacobi symbol aloud?

Tags: terminology, jacobi-symbol

Suppose you're reading aloud the Jacobi symbol "$J(x, N) = -1$".  Which pronunciation you find more natural?

Comment: Using that notation, I would say just "J of x N" or even "J x N". With the notation $(x|N)$ or $(\frac xN)$, I have said "Jacobi symbol x N", or maybe "Jacobi x N" if I had to say it several times.

Comment: What do you think of "Jacobi symbol of $x$ over $N$" alluding to the fact that it looks like a fraction?  If I read it like that, it will trigger people's memory of the symbol.

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: @GregMartin  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCMcu18sigc